# Prove $\lim\limits_{p\to 0}\|f\|_p= e^{\int \ln |f|d\mu}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Assume $\mu(X)=1$ and $\|f\|_r<\infty$ for some $r>0$, and prove that  $$\lim\limits_{p\to 0}\|f\|_p= e^{\int \ln |f|d\mu}$$ if $e^{-\infty}$ is defined to be $0$.

### My Work

It is clear that $$\ln\|f\|_p=(1/p)\ln\bigg(\int_{X}|f|^pd\mu\bigg)\geq (1/p)\bigg(\int_{X}\ln|f|^pd\mu\bigg)= \bigg(\int_{X}\ln|f|d\mu\bigg) $$

thus $$\|f\|_p \geq e^{\int_{X}\ln|f|d\mu}$$

---I am stuck here---

Comment: have you tried testing against simple functions?

Comment: @user90189 You get $\ln(||f||_p)=\frac{1}{p}\ln(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|^p\mu(A_{i}))$ which doesn't seem to give me anything interesting

Comment: @user90189 Nevermind applying l hopistal  rule on that gives the desired equality.

Comment: The second term in your equation has limit $\frac{d}{dp} (\ln \int_X |f|^p \, d\mu) \mid_{p=0}$ so if you could establish some integrable dominating function of the derivative $|f|^p \ln |f|$ for $p$ near 0 then you could apply the appropriate corollary of the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F_{p}$ be the function on $X$ defined by
$$
F_{p}(x)=\frac{1}{p}(\lvert f(x)\rvert^{p}-1)
$$
Suppose that $f$ is nonzero almost everywhere, and for any positive $p$ at most $r$, consider the following chain of inequalities:
$$
\int_{X}\log\lvert f\rvert \:d\mu \leq \log\lVert f\rVert_{p} \leq \int_{X}F_{p} \:d\mu < \infty. \tag{*}
$$
The first follows from Jensen's inequality applied to $p\log\lvert f\rvert$, the second from the assumption $\mu(X)=1$ and the inequality $\log{x}\leq x-1$, and the third from the fact that $\mu(X)=1$. The same inequalities remain true even if $f$ vanishes in a set of positive measure since $\log{0}=-\infty$.

When $f(x)\neq 0$, by l'Hospital's rule,
$$
\lim_{p\to 0} F_{p}(x)=\log\lvert f(x)\rvert,
$$
The standard convergence theorems (upon justification) allow you to squeeze (*) as $p\to 0$.